# Imported images in csv file not working in webpage

Tags: html, django, django-media

I imported a CSV file with multiple columns, one of them is for images and it's in this format

```
<div class="parent">
<img class="img" title="" src=" {% static 'assets/images/thumb/1537.png' %} "width="64" height="64">
</div>
```

Everything works when I include the model on my index.html, but the image line becomes like a string and not an image.

**models.py**

```
class Account(models.Model):
    Code = models.IntegerField(__("Code"))
    Crystls= models.IntegerField(__("Crystls"))
    Price = models.IntegerField(__("Price"))
    Detail = models.CharField(__("Detail"), max_length=255)
    Image = models.ImageField(__("Image"), max_length=255)
```

**index.html**

```
{% for account in account  %}

<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">{{account.Code}}</td>
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;"><img src=" {% static 'assets/images/assets/crystls.png' %} " width="22" height="22" style="padding-bottom:3px;" />{{account.Crystls}}</td>
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">{{account.Price}}</td>
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;"><a target="_blank" href=" {% static 'account61f3.html?id_xml=001660' %} " ><input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value={{account.Detail}} /></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="5">                
        {{account.Image}}
    </td>
  {% endfor %}
</tr><tr >
```

Comment: Files stored in ImageField are not **static** they are **media**. How to show image from ImageField - there is a bunch of such questions on so with answers already, please use search. [ImageField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models)

Comment: Also please consider following [django coding style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style) model attributes should be in lower_snake_case

Comment: I don't know how much this is your real code but in some cases spaces in HTML do really matter. Missing or extra ones. Consider validating final page markup using [this service](https://validator.w3.org/) for example.

Comment: It's all my code and the spaces is perfect, it's just on here there is a difference